# Don't have mobile and/or iOS options in delphi/c++ builder

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

First of all, I am so sorry for the STUPID question but I am tired of searching google for the answer.  I don’t have the option to create mobile and/or iOS applications in Delphi and C++ builder, is there something I need to setup before I can see those options?

[image]

I am currently using RAD XE3 Update 1 version 17.0.4723.  Perhaps the version I have does not come with the options I need.

Comment: You can't use XE3 to create iOS apps, you must upgrade to XE4.

Comment: @RRUZ It is my understanding that cross-platform was introduced with XE2 - http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41595

Comment: Yes, but the iOS development support was removed in XE3 and reintroduced in XE4.

Comment: I have Xe4 architect and have the same problem... there's no mobile option

Comment: @ÁbrahámEndre: XE4 Architect does indeed come with support for mobile (iOS) development. `File->New->Other->Delphi Projects->FireMonkey mobile app`. XE4 includes this in Delphi Architect, Ultimate, and Enterprise SKUs (it's a paid add-on for the Professional SKU). RAD Studio XE4 includes iOS development in Architect, Ultimate, Enterprise, and Professional SKUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple answer:

XE2 allowed you to create iOS apps using the open source version of FireMonkey and FreePascal in Xcode.

XE3, which was meant to contain a native iOS compiler, got rid of that, but the iOS compiler was not finished in time.

To program natively for iOS, you must use XE4 (or later). This has options to create iOS apps (File | New | Other | Delphi projects | FireMonkey mobile app) .

So sorry, with XE3 you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for mobile in XE3. It was added in XE2 using FPC compiler, removed from XE3 and then restored for XE4 using new Embarcadero mobile compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Right now IOS(Iphone/Ipad) is supported in the following,

XE4 - Architect,Ultimate and Enterprise versions.

XE4 - Professional + additional mobile add-on pack(~ 449 dollars offer).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is included in Rad Studio Pro, without extra cost.